# How to see the messages with all the mentions of my name in specific slack Channel

Tags: slack, slack-integration

My slack group is called: TransBio_NB.
transbionb.slack.com.

In the channel called "subgroup generative modeling," I want to find all the messages where my name @juan P. Munoz Diaz, was mentioned by my professor @Jesper Tegner or anyone in the group. (both options are ok).

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the mentions of your name using the "Mentions & reactions" section on the left sidebar:
[image: How to see mentions]